# Android in app purchases: is it possible to buy few subscriptions at same time?

Tags: android, in-app, subscriptions

From google documentation I don't clearly understand -
Is it only one subscription can be active at same time?
Or is it possible to buy few subscriptions simultaneously?

Please explain it for me.

Comment: What part of the documentation is unclear, can you quote? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wont to provide in my application few subscriptions. For example - subscription1, subscription 2, subscription3. Is it possible to buy all 3 subscriptions at same time? Or only 1 susbcription can be active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple products and configure attributes for subscription for each subscription product

Quoting [the docs for configuring subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#administering)

> To create and manage subscriptions, you can use the Developer Console
>   to set up a product list for the app, then configure these attributes
>   for each subscription product:
>
> ```
> Purchase Type: always set to Subscription
> Subscription ID: An identifier for the subscription
> Publishing State: Unpublished/Published
> Language: The default language for displaying the subscription
> Title: The title of the subscription product
> Description: Details that tell the user about the subscription
> Price: Default price of subscription per recurrence
> Recurrence: Interval of billing recurrence
> Additional currency pricing (can be auto-filled)
> ```

Comment: I made small test application and you are right. it's possible to buy few subscriptions at same time.